# I want to show the time pickup with time interval

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I got the `start time`,`end time`,`break start`,`break end` and `time interval` too.

```
   $start_time='9:00';
   $end_time='15:00';
   $break_start='13:00';
   $break_end='14:00';
   $time_interval='60';
```

The output i want will be like below. The user pick the time slot from this.

```
9:00 to 10:00
10:00 to 11:00
11:00 to 12:00
12:00 to 13:00
14:00 to 15:00
```

I am trying to figure this out but no idea how  to do it.

Comment: Your date are all strings, so put quotes

Comment: Is this also bound to a specific date, or are the times independent of actual days? If the former, you can create a concrete **timestamp** for a specific date and time and use PHP's date functions/objects to help you a lot. Otherwise you'll just have to write a bunch of code manually counting minutes and hours. That's a bit too broad to do here really.

Comment: What you actualy want to do ? Some kind of dropdown menu ?

Comment: radio button for pickup time

Comment: Ok I just coded a dropdown list. I do it again with radios

Comment: post for dropdown i will do the next..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this....

```
    $start_time='9:00';
    $end_time='15:00';
    $break_start='13:00';
    $break_end='14:00';
    $time_interval='60';
    for($i=strtotime($start_time);$i<=strtotime($end_time);$i=$i+(60*$time_interval))
    {
        if(strtotime($start_time) < $i)
        {
            $workstart=date('H:i',($i-(60*$time_interval)));
            $workend=date('H:i', $i);
            if(strtotime($break_start) !=$i-(60*$time_interval) && strtotime($break_end) !=$i)
            {
                echo $workstart.' to '.$workend;
                echo "</br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
09:00 to 10:00
10:00 to 11:00
11:00 to 12:00
12:00 to 13:00
14:00 to 15:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
     $start_time= new DateTime("9:00");
     $end_time= new DateTime("15:00");
     $break_start= new DateTime("13:00");
     $break_end= new DateTime("14:00");
     $time_interval= DateInterval::createFromDateString('60 min');

    $times    = new DatePeriod($start_time, $time_interval, $end_time);

foreach ($times as $time) {
    echo "<input type='radio'>";
    echo $time->format('H:i'), '-', 
         $time->add($time_interval)->format('H:i'), "\n";
         echo "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Put the name you want to your radios

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$start_time='9:00';
$end_time='15:00';
$break_start='13:00';
$break_end='14:00';
$time_interval='60';

for($i=strtotime($start_time);$i<strtotime($end_time); $i=$i+($time_interval*60))
{
    if(!($i>=strtotime($break_start) && $i<strtotime($break_end)))
        echo date("H:i",$i).' to '.date("H:i",($i+($time_interval*60))).'<Br/>';        
}
?>
```